# Upload with Chrome on IOS almost fixed - no status

Tags: fine-uploader

Have upgraded to 5.2 and pleased to find that IOS8 users can upload now on Chrome for IOS>
However, the status progress bar does not how ( it does with Safari)

Comment: while this is not a bug, it reads like a bug report. Going forward, bug reports (and feature requests) should be opened in the project's GitHub issue tracker instead.

Comment: Also note that this version did not fix uploading on chrome -it always worked. I simply turned off a workaround that prevented uploading videos due to a crash issue with earlier versions of iOS8 chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome on iOS does not support the upload progress event. As a result, fine uploader does not render a progress bar for this or any other browser with this deficiency.